# How to only include specific fields when returning all documents from a collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using `NodeJS` and `MongoDB`. I am trying to query my DB and return all documents from a collection, but I'm also trying to limit which fields get returned.

I am having trouble, here is my code.

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

```
collection.find(
      { type: 1 }, 
      {'_id': 0, 'firstName': 1, 'lastName': 1, 'email': 1, 'zip': 1}, 
      function(err, allUsersObject) 
     {
         return res.send({data: allUsersObject, status: 200});
    });
```

Comment: What kind of issue you are getting? Please explain

Comment: Apologies. My query was not working and was returning ALL fields. @rgins16 pointed out what I was doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing '{fields: }'. I fixed your query for you, see below:

```
collection.find(
      { type: 1 }, 
      {fields: 
        {'_id': 0, 'firstName': 1, 'lastName': 1, 'email': 1, 'zip': 1}
      }, function(err, allUsersObject) {

      return res.send({data: allUsersObject, status: 200});
    });
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, I was indeed missing '{fields: }'.